# Issue with streaming AVI files

Tags: streaming, avi

I am writing a video streaming server application. I have an AVI file and I have put it on IIS 7 for streaming. I found that client cannot jump to an arbitrary location of the media, if the media is not buffered already. I think some meta-data is missing during recording?

After searching, I think, Windows Media Player could not jump to any arbitrary location before buffered locally, since Index block of AVI (needed for seeking) is stored at the end of file.

Here is an example, if my recorded avi video is 10 mins, and now I am playing to the 4th mins, and the local buffered streaming media is buffered to the 5th mins, I cannot jump to any time after the 5th mins, like the 7th mins in Windows Media Player.

I did not face the same issue with other formats like asf/wmv. So I think it is an AVI issue rather than server or any other environmental issue.

My questions are,

1. What is the actual reason for not being able to jump to arbitrary location for AVI file, before it is buffered?
2. Any solutions or workarounds? Can I use other smarter players instead, which can handle this issue or can I add some code fix at the server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already discovered yourself, index is written at the end of avi containers. That's why avi format is not good for streaming.

You should convert your video to some other format which has the indexing information at the beginning. For example, flv, wmv, ogg/theora, etc.

Comment: Hi Milan, conversion is too slow... Do you have any ideas to speed up? I have a video of 30mins, and it takes 20 mins to convert to flv. My computer is powerful, 4G RAM and 2 CPUs. Input avi file size is about 150M Bytes.

Comment: @Milan, sorry another question. If you think converting to other format like flv/wmv is the best solution, could you recommend some video conversion solutions, like H/W? I think using CPU to convert video is really slow... :-)

Comment: Well, if you want to keep the quality, it has to take the time. It would be best if you had some non-lossy source before it was in avi format. For encoding/recoding I use mencoder and ffmpeg programs, but there are many of them out there. Maybe you should post a separate question about this.

Comment: Hi Milan, 1. "Well, if you want to keep the quality, it has to take the time." -- I do not need quality, I just need to speed-up encoding process as fast as possible. Do you have any advice?

Comment: 2. " It would be best if you had some non-lossy source before it was in avi format" -- I am using Camtasia to record screen for a Demo, I think in this case there is no non-lossy source, correct?

Comment: Maybe you could convert the video from AVI to ASF format using a simple copy (i.e. the content is the same, but container changes). Try this program for example: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MediaCoder

Comment: Great idea Milan! I have downloaded and installed MediaCoder, but (I am a new user) I did not find an option for me to copy from avi to asf. Could you show me more instructions?

Comment: Perhaps you would get more answers asking at a forum specialized for this. SO is only about programming, after all. Try here: http://www.videohelp.com

Comment: Thanks Milan, I have found this videohelp forum quite useful.

Comment: @Milan, I have started a new topic as you suggested above to discuss further new topic, if you have expertise, please help here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743429/codes-to-convert-from-avi-to-asf

Comment: I see some time has passed, but nevertheless.

I have the exact same problem with .avi streaming. The solution I found that works best is to only change the container type. Just copy both the video and audio streams and change the container to .mp4 (in my case), this enables streaming and seeking on the web player, and it is a fast operation.