# codes to convert from avi to asf

Tags: avi, asf

No matter what library/SDK to use, I want to convert from avi to asf very quickly (I could even sacrifice some quality of video and audio). I am working on Windows platform (Vista and 2008 Server), better .Net SDK/code, C++ code is also fine. :-)

I learned from the below link, that there could be a very quick way to convert from avi to asf to support streaming better, as mentioned "could convert the video from AVI to ASF format using a simple copy (i.e. the content is the same, but container changes).". My question is after some hours of study and trial various SDK/tools, as a newbie, I do not know how to begin with so I am asking for reference sample code to do this task. :-)

(as this is a different issue, we decide to start a new topic. :-) )

[Issue with streaming AVI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743220/streaming-avi-file-issue)

thanks in advance,
George

EDIT 1:

I have tried to get the binary of ffmpeg from,

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/ffmpeg-latest-mingw32-static.tar.bz2

then run the following command,

```
C:\software\ffmpeg-latest-mingw32-static\bin>ffmpeg.exe -i test.avi -acodec copy
 -vcodec copy test.asf
FFmpeg version SVN-r18506, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --prefix=/mingw --cross-prefix=i686-ming
w32- --cc=ccache-i686-mingw32-gcc --target-os=mingw32 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --e
nable-avisynth --enable-gpl --enable-zlib --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enabl
e-libfaac --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libo
penjpeg --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaad -
-enable-libschroedinger --enable-libx264
  libavutil     50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0
  libavcodec    52.25. 0 / 52.25. 0
  libavformat   52.32. 0 / 52.32. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  built on Apr 14 2009 04:04:47, gcc: 4.2.4
Input #0, avi, from 'test.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:44.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5291 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: msvideo1, rgb555le, 1280x1024, 5 tbr, 5 tbn, 5 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 352 kb/s
Output #0, asf, to 'test.asf':
    Stream #0.0: Video: CRAM / 0x4D415243, rgb555le, 1280x1024, q=2-31, 1k tbn,
5 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 352 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=  224 fps=222 q=-1.0 Lsize=   29426kB time=44.80 bitrate=5380.7kbits/s

video:26910kB audio:1932kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.023317%

C:\software\ffmpeg-latest-mingw32-static\bin>
```

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/webhelp/default.aspx?&mpver=11.0.6001.7000&id=C00D11B1&contextid=230&originalid=C00D36E6

then have the following error when using Windows Media Player to play it, does anyone have any ideas?

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/webhelp/default.aspx?&mpver=11.0.6001.7000&id=C00D11B1&contextid=230&originalid=C00D36E6

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use FFMPEG and run a command like this (I haven't tried):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i test.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy test.asf
```

Comment: @Milan, sorry for a very stupid question. :-)

I did not find binary download for ffmpeg on Windows platform, and I only see download for source codes? Any binary download? I did not have compiler on my machine and I want to have a quick try.

Comment: +1 I don't know what options are available from code but this definitely sounds like a job for FFMPEG.

Comment: @Milan, I have tried that the link you provided only contains source code, no binary. If I am wrong to find it, could you point me the exact link please?

Comment: @capar, "but this definitely sounds like a job for FFMPEG" -- you mean using ffmpeg to do such thing is the right choice?

Comment: @Milan, I have got a binary version of ffmpeg, and I have tried and met with some issues when playing the generated asf file. I posted all my steps in EDIT 1 section in my original post. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: I found ffmpeg.exe (1.64ΜΒ) in the root folder of eRightSoft\SUPER after installing supersetup.exe (27.6MB) from http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html .
Finding the link to download is kind of a challenge, since those guys use heavy advertising to make their money.

Comment: Just a quick note: don't use ASF if your video is H.264/AVC - ASF doesn't support b-frames. FLV or MP4 is a better idea in this case.